# HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name is incorrect but only for me

Tags: asp.net, iis

We have a number of webpages that employees can access. I have a table, in a database, which determines who can access the individual pieces.

I use HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name, to get the current username, and then determine whether they are allowed to access the page they are requesting. If not, they are redirected to an access denied page, which has contact details where they can request access.

This is been working for months and is still working for everybody, except me! As well as my usual active directory account, I have what we call a developer account to login to servers et cetera. When I run the webpages on my PC, either through visual studio or IIS, I have determined that it is working because it is using my standard active directory account.

I am not aware of making any changes. I was actually just going through the pages as part of a documentation exercise.

However, as soon as I try to browse the pages on the server, it appears to be using my developer account! How do I know this? Firstly, I have built a test page that displays the current username. Secondly, I have an audit table, which records who try to access what page, when and whether they were allowed access.

Yes I could add my developer account to the users table but that would obviously not be my preferred solution. I have been working on something else for the past few days (nothing to do with this) and based on the audit table, I think this problem started today.

Any ideas?

Comment: When you say "browse the pages on the server" do you mean you're using RDP to connect to it, and then run a browser there? What user account do you use to log into the server?

Comment: `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` should not be used in most cases. Use the `User` property of the page, or the controller instead.

Comment: Browse means from my PC but obviously the URL is pointing to the server. I know I cannot do from the server, because it would pick up the user that was logged into the server.

To emphasise it is only a problem on one PC. If I remote my office PC and try from there it works. 3 other colleagues have tried it from their PC and it works.

Also it is only an ASPX web application, we never really got round to upgrading to MVC or . Net CORE.

Comment: It's probably just your browser caching the credentials on your machine that you tried in the past. Try a different browser. I've noticed Chrome in particular is funny when it comes to AD and reusing credentials.

Comment: It would seem to be a caching problem but I cannot solve this. Firefox was not installed therefore I installed it and on my test page it shows the correct user. Meanwhile i.e., edge and chrome still will not play ball! I have cleared all my history, passwords (that will be a pain in the neck) from chrome-it is still using the developer account. I even tried to uninstall it but there is no mention of chrome in my programs list.

Comment: Still doesn't explain why, because I do not use my developer account to browse these pages and I know that because my developer account has never been added as a user to any of the pages.